# Only Run @Before If Not Logged In(Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I need to test a Component that appears after the login. For that i need to login and i do that like that:

```
@Before
    fun login(){

        val email = composeTestRule.onNode(hasTestTag("email"))
        val password = composeTestRule.onNode(hasTestTag("password"))
        val loginButton = composeTestRule.onNode(hasTestTag("login"))


        
            email.performTextInput("xxxxx")
            password.performTextInput("xxxxxx")
            loginButton.performClick()
            Thread.sleep(1000)

    }
```

The problem is, that if the client is logged in already this functions should not be executed. Is there any way to execute this function only when the field "email" is displayed?

Comment: You can check inside the function what is being displayed and proceed accordingly.

Comment: But how can i check that? If i use .assertIsDisplayed it dont return a Boolean. It only throws an error and thats not what i want. Is there a isDisplayed function or somthing?

Comment: @EliahGerber you can try / catch the error and.. run the code if they're not logged in in the catch block